# Select parent and first child element which has more than one child element

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

Query is to get the first child element with it's value where the corresponding parent element should have more than one child element.

Here, tricky is issue is that parent and child element is generated dynamically. i.e. we doesn't know about the parent and child names

Here is the XML Input:

```html
<PageTwo>
   <List25>No</List25>
   <List11>Air Gun|Gun</List11>
   <Multilist02>
    <Value>.204</Value>
    <Value>.22</Value>
    <Value>.243</Value>
   </Multilist02>
   <Multilist05>
    <Value>Air Gun|NOS|NOS</Value>
    <Value>Optic|Binocular|ZULU5</Value>
   </Multilist05>
   <List23>DAK</List23>
   <Text01>NA</Text01>
   <List13>EA</List13>
   <List26>No</List26>
   <List07>IN</List07>
   <List08>LB</List08>
  </PageTwo>
```

In the above XML, **Multilist** contains more than one child value and has to extract the first child element with Value

Sample [Excepted] Output

```html
            <Multilist02>
       <Value>.204</Value>
   </Multilist02>
   <Multilist05>
    <Value>Air Gun|NOS|NOS</Value>
   </Multilist05>
```

As I said before, in the incoming xml we doesn't know what name will come for parent and child element.

I tried below XSLT and able to extract the first child but unable to cover the child with corresponding parent element

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2014/08/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2014/08/ http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2014/08/aXML.xsd">
<xsl:template match="/"> 
<xsl:for-each select="/PageTwo/*">
<xsl:for-each select="*">
 <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
<xsl:if test="$i = 1">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Generated Output is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Value>.204</Value><Value>Air Gun|NOS|NOS</Value>
```

Kindly help me on this issue

**EDIT:** Below answer resolved above question which I accepted as answer

Adding one more query on above XML Input file with adding attributes to root node.

**New Input:** Added attributes to root node

```html
<PageTwo  xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2/2/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2/2/ http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2/2/aXML.xsd" creator="admin, nawaz(nawaz)">
   <List25>No</List25>
   <List11>Air Gun|Gun</List11>
   <Multilist02>
    <Value>.204</Value>
    <Value>.22</Value>
    <Value>.243</Value>
   </Multilist02>
   <Multilist05>
    <Value>Air Gun|NOS|NOS</Value>
    <Value>Optic|Binocular|ZULU5</Value>
   </Multilist05>
   <List23>DAK</List23>
   <Text01>NA</Text01>
   <List13>EA</List13>
   <List26>No</List26>
   <List07>IN</List07>
   <List08>LB</List08>
  </PageTwo>
```

Suppose if I want parse the element with their name rather specifying `*` on the below solution which I accepted as answer

**Current answer**

```html
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*[*[2]]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@* | *[1]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Even I am able to parse the elements by specifying their corresponding name when **attributes are not present in the root node**. But I would like to parse the element with their name with root node attributes to display

**Excepted Solution**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><PageTwo xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2/2/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2/2/ http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2/2/aXML.xsd" creator="admin, nawaz(nawaz)">
  <Multilist02>
       <Value>.204</Value>
  </Multilist02>
  <Multilist05>
    <Value>Air Gun|NOS|NOS</Value>
  </Multilist05>
</PageTwo>
```

**condition** Parse the element with their names

Comment: Is `<Multilist02>
       <Value>.204</Value>
   </Multilist02>
   <Multilist05>
    <Value>Air Gun|NOS|NOS</Value>
   </Multilist05>` the complete output you want, no other elements, no root element?

Comment: @MartinHonnen yes I want only <Multilist02> <Value>.204</Value> </Multilist02> <Multilist05> <Value>Air Gun|NOS|NOS</Value> </Multilist05>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*[*[2]]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@* | *[1]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Would like to know the use of "@* | *[1]". Suppose if one more super parent on top the above XML, will it work?

Comment: If you have more levels then please edit your question and show us a sample of that and the corresponding output you want, plus the rules determining the output you want. Currently the `<xsl:apply-templates select="*/*[*[2]]"/>` processes all child elements of the root element which have at least two child elements, and the second template then simply make a shallow copy of those elements plus copying the first child element.

Comment: I got it, if we have greater parent element then we can parse by adding /* with respect to number of levels